# On execution of a pivot i am getting ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle, pivot, ora-00936

On execution of the following sql statement i am getting an error **[Error] Execution (23: 69): ORA-00936: missing expression**

```
select sno,nam,gender,salary from cus pivot xml (count(sno) for nam in (any));
```

Can we use a column name without any grouping expressions?
Actually i want the entire a column names as the row header for the particular table.
thanks in advance

let the table be

```
---------   --------    -----------------------

name        sno        salary

---------   --------    -----------------------

sony         1         20000

sweety       2         17500
```

the above is the sample table.the result i wish is as follows

```
---------   --------    

snoy        sweety        

---------   --------

1            2
20000        17500
```

for two values i can use IN operator but  i had 50 rows or 50 values but how can i display them.

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) states that _"The ANY keyword is used only in conjunction with the XML keyword"_.

Comment: thanks,why should we use aggregate functions in the pivot method? if i want all column names as header for the table then how can we use this pivot element?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment. Maybe it would be better to post some sample data and the result you want from that data to give people something to work towards.

Comment: @Ben i had modified the query and i had shown some sample data